# How to automatically download the excel file if number of records in DataTable is more than 1 lac record on success call of AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a dataTable which has more than 100 000 records. I am trying to export that data in excel and i want to have downloaded automatically if number of record is more than 100k.

In controller action method:

```
if (res.Count > 40000)
{
  ExportDataToExcel(parameters);
}
```

and then i have created a function :

```
public void ExportDataToExcel(some parameters)
         {


             DataTable tbl = new DataTable("SomeReport");
             tbl = objCommon.GetGridDataTableFormat(some parameters);// this function is fetching me `datatable` 


             tbl.TableName = "Report";
               using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
               {

                   wb.Worksheets.Add(tbl);
                  // wb.SaveAs("DiscountReport-" + DateTime.Now);
                   wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                   wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;

                 Response.Clear();
                 Response.Buffer = true;
                 Response.Charset = "";
                 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= DiscountReport.xlsx");

                 using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                 {
                     wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                     MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                     Response.Flush();
                     Response.End();
                 }

               }
```

After this it returning to Ajax, success:

```
 success: function(data) {

something 
}
```

The data which is coming in argument part of above function is as follows:

[image: data coming in argument of success function]

I just needed to export this data to excel and have it downloaded automatically.Is it possible? Or should i change my approach.

EDIT: 
@palash:
I must be doing something wrong in implementation part.  Kind of feels like spoonfeeding. but here is how i have implemented your code after understanding logic.:

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: '/Reports/_GetDiscountGrid',
                    data: {
                        State: stat,
                        Zone: zon,
                        Amrac: amr,
                        Store: store,
                        Hierarchy: hirarcy,
                        DiscountType: discountType,
                        Itemcategorycode: itemcatCode,
                        Itemcode: code,
                        Period: period,
                        OfferNo: offernumber
                    },
                    datatype: "html",
                    type:"GET",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#tbldiscountDIV').empty();

                        if (typeof (data) == "string") {
                            $('#tbldiscountDIV2').show();
                            DownLoadSheet(data, "DiscountReport.xlsx");
                        }
```

After this the function i have defined as :

```
function DownLoadSheet(data,fileName)
     {

         const a = document.createElement("a");
         document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style="display:none";
        return function (data,fileName)
        {
            const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlfomrats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" }),
                url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.href=url;
            a.download=fileName;
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
         }//return for function end
         a.href = url;
         var temp = blob;
     }
```

After it is returning to AJAX call and exiting . I found that target and download arguments are empty, where did i go wrong ?

[DATA in excel format[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTTaD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the `success` method actually the xlsx file is returned as a response. You can just download it like:

```
const DownloadSheet = (function() {
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = "display: none";
  return function(data, fileName) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"}),
      url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };
}());

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  success: function(response) {
     DownloadSheet(response, 'DiscountReport.xlsx')
  }
});
```

Comment: @palash: Please check the edited part and the image i have added . I know i am close but somewhere in implementation part i am going wrong

Comment: No need to check `if (typeof (data) == "string")` just run `DownLoadSheet(data, "DiscountReport.xlsx");` inside success and test again.